# How to center and zoom a Google Map using the address bar

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a page with a Google Map generated. I want to be able to use the address bar to change the zoom and center point. E. g.:

```
www.example.com/mymap?zoom=10&center=10,15
www.example.com/mymap?zoom=10&lat=10&lng=15
```

I remember that there was a similar combination that worked, but now I can't get any results with it.

Here is my function:

```
function initialize() {
// create the map
var myOptions = {
zoom: 5,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(10,15),
mapTypeControl: true,
mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
navigationControl: true,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
new google.maps.LatLng(8, 12),
new google.maps.LatLng(12, 18));

var options = {
bounds: defaultBounds
};

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
infowindow.close();
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
{ size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this (translated to the Google Maps API v3 from [Mike Williams' v2 tutorial](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/linktothis.htm)):

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_linktothis.html?lat=42.359783&lng=-71.092800&zoom=18&type=h

Comment: Yes, I have seen that, but shouldn't this behaviour be enabled by default? When I apply this URL "addition" (?lat=42.359783&lng=-71.092800&zoom=10) to my page nothing happens, the page just reloads once.

Comment: No, that behavior is not enabled by default.  If your map is using the Google Maps API v3 (which is the code you posted and the tag you applied to the question), you have to code that functionality yourself (like that example).  If you are using Google Maps, there are URL parameters available (they used to be documented on mapki.com but that seems to be gone right now).

Comment: This does seem easy, but the problem is that I'm using it along with your example of marker categories (http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_categories.html). Something is conflicting, probably this "parseFloat" part, but if I remove it, then it won't work.

Comment: You just need to make it compatible with the rest of the code on your page, shouldn't be too hard if you understand the code you wrote and think about what the query string processing is doing.  The latitude and longitude should both be floating point numbers; I'm not sure what you mean by "this parseFloat part".

Comment: I have parseFloat variable (e. g. var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));) already for parsing XML document (implemented from your example with categories). And now in this example there is again parseFloat command. Aren't they both essential for their functions? That's why I'm not sure how to combine it.

Comment: [parseFloat](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp) takes an argument and returns a floating point number (or NaN if the argument can't be translated into a floating point number). Why would there be an issue in using it for the same thing in two different places in your code?

Comment: OK, glad to hear that it won't conflict. I will experiment with it and let you know when I find the solution. Thank you for the help!

Comment: It works, ofc! :) There are no conflicts, I just didn't close one of the functions properly, that is why it didn't work at first. One thing remaining to solve - how can I prevent page refresh after clicking "Link to this page"? Ideally, it would just open a small modal window where you can copy the link from.

Comment: Nevermind, I found a solution, I can just remove the link tags and that's it.